# « Il va y en avoir » prononcé « il va n'en avoir » ?

Tags: prononciation, oral, euphonie

Dans une [séquence](https://youtu.be/89CAY3gTWCo) de film on entend un enfant dire :

> Le château fort qu'on va faire, là, les murs vont être large « comme
> ça »,
>  Il va être plus gros que ma maison, plus haut que les
> arbres,
>  Il va, il va être super impressionnant, il va **n'en** avoir juste
> « un » château fort comme ça,
>  Avec des tours, des créneaux, plein de
> décorations, des portes, des fenêtres,
>  Toutes des affaires secrètes,
> on va même pouvoir y manger dedans,
>  Il va avoir tout qu'est-ce
> qu'on pourra mettre,
>  Il va être vraiment super beau, comme tous
> les châteaux du Moyen Âge,
>  Super super beau.
>
> [ François « Les Lunettes » ds. la [*Guerre des tuques*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Guerre_des_tuques) (Mélançon,
> 1984) ]

La prononciation « il va **n'en** avoir » (plutôt que *y en avoir*) relève-t-elle d'une prononciation enfantine ou d'une stratégie de résolution de [hiatus](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=hiatus&id=2514) et dans ce dernier cas est-elle régionale ([Québec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Consonnes)) ; existe-t-il un *n* euphonique comme le [*s*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2512) ou le [*t*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2513) ou est-ce par haplologie ou autrement ; y a-t-il une autre stratégie de prononciation de « il va y en avoir », est-ce plus court que dans la séquence ou en quoi ça diffère ?

Comment: Ce serait du français hexagonal je dirais prononciation enfantine, mais pour ce qui est du français québécois aucune idée.

Comment: La partie de la question "y a-t-il une autre stratégie de prononciation de « il va y en avoir »" n'est pas limitée au Québec. Si on pense que _n'en avoir_ ne sera jamais employé chez les adultes, certainement qu'on aura « y'en » du moins ou on accepte systématiquement le hiatus ici généralement ? @None

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que l'omission de *y* dans cette phrase est une erreur causée par la complexité de la structure. On doit donc considérer ce que dit l'enfant acteur comme une variante de *il va en avoir* (français écrit) et non de *il va y en avoir*.

Évidemment, le sens de la phrase exige *y*.

En français québécois familier, le pronom *en* a deux autres formes, selon le contexte phonétique.

On dit *n'* (consonne géminee) entre voyelles, et *n'en* après une voyelle mais devant une consonne.

- Du pain, on n'a. (On en a)
- Du pain, i n-n'a. (Il en a - le *l* ne fait pas partie du pronom)
- Du pain, j'en ai. (Aucun changement)
- Du pain, vous n'en voulez? (Vous en voulez?)

Tout ça, ce ne sont nullement des erreurs d'élocution. Ici, le rétablissement du *n'en* plein entre voyelles (à la place de *I va n-n'avoir*) me semble être une variante mineure et tout à fait possible.

Comment: Merci, ah ok, j'avais pas pensé à _I va n-n'avoir_, juste à _y'en_. L'emploi de la consonne géminée c'est au Québec et pas en France si je comprends bien ton propos donc ? Enfin je suis un peu surpris que tu dises que de toute façon se serait _va y en avoir_ sans  le il, je semble avoir davantage besoin d'ancrer ça avec le son i du pronom il d'abord (i/y va n n'avoir) mais très faible, un peu comme _yvonne_.

Comment: Ça se peut. J'ai toujours eu l'impression que c'était une influence normative, ce *i*, mais je vais enlever cette partie-là de ce que j'ai écrit. Concernant la consonne géminée, je peux seulement dire que ça ne fait pas partie du français "correct" en France, mais je n'ai pas l'expertise pour me prononcer sur les français populaires et régionaux. En passant, merci pour ce que tu as écrit après mon autre réponse. Malheureusement j'avais déjà perdu les cookies qui me donnaient accès à ce compte-là.

Comment: C'est normal que tu n'aies pas pensé a autre chose que *y en* puisque c'était ça qui était commandé par le sens de la phrase.

Comment: Merci, avec plaisir ! C'était bien mérité ! En passant, tu peux facilement essayer au besoin faire des représentations pour rapatrier tes contenus et la réputation de l'autre compte en communiquant avec les modérateurs ou dans le profil il y a une option peut-être. En écrivant en anglais c'est possible de faire une démontration d'adéquation comme tu as écrit un texte assez long justement et qu'il y a des trucs qui ne mentent pas. Ceci dit, oui bien je m'intéresse à tout ça mais je vois bien qu'il me manque bien des bases, surtout la phonétique, pour vraiment orienter ma curiosité. Entk merci !

Comment: Je ne tiens pas à avoir un compte permanent sur Stack Exchange. Il y avait une époque où je participais beaucoup sur le site des maths, mais j'en ai eu marre de la culture de ce site. Maintenant, je n'ai plus de compte, alors si je vois une question à laquelle je veux répondre (pour aider quelqu'un en maths, par exemple), je repars de zéro, et je conserve l'identité pendant quelques jours. Pour les bases en phonétique, j'avais appris ça avec *Linguistics: An Introduction* de Radford. Maintenant, comme les exemples sont souvent tirés de l'anglais, ça se peut que tu trouves ça moins intéressant.

Comment: @Anonymous Je comprends, la réputation (les points) c'est pas grave, le site permet en effet de répondre donc c'est que la création de contenu est valorisée. Merci, non non tout est intéressant. Sur le profil de John Lawler sur English LU j'ai ramassé un ensemble de notes de cours etc. Un Linguistics 101. Parfois je décide de régarder un truc etc. _Jack of all trades_ d'une certaine manière. Ça peut être ça ou Haskell ou peu importe...

Comment: Je ne suis pas étonné que tu penses ça du système de points, surtout que tu les donnes.